# What does two vertical lines and super.select mean in a code block?

Tags: ruby

What does the following actually mean?

```
def method
  super.select { |a| a.meets_condition? || true }
end
```

I'm particularly struggling with || in this context. It is hard to find answers to this kind of question with a search engine.

What does the `super.select` do?

What does the method do if the "|| true" part is removed?

Comment: There's info on `super` on https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/keywords_rdoc.html. It calls "the current method in a superclass".  `||` is a Boolean OR.

Comment: Perhaps it is just me, but I think this example doesn't make much sense. Return all entries for which a condition is true or `true`? In other words, always return all entries which were returned from `super`? What is the point of this method then?

Comment: @orde Not quite on `||`, `a || b` is an expression that evaluates to `a` if `a` is truthy and `b` otherwise, the value of the expression isn't necessarily `true` or `false`.

Comment: @mu is too short: thx for the clarification. Is that defined in the docs or just implicit?

Comment: @orde Should be documented but I'm not aware of any decent up-to-date documentation of what "Ruby" is. This is fairly common behavior, `||` works like this in JavaScript, Perl, ...

Comment: @muistooshort: For basic stuff, the ISO Ruby Language Specification still works. The behavior of the boolean operators is not going to change any time soon (even though I wish they would actually translate into method calls like all other operators). As a reference, there is *The Ruby Programming Language* written by David Flanagan and matz himself. Other than that, [The Ruby Spec Suite](https://github.com/ruby/spec), which is the new revived RubySpec. Boolean `||` is here: https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/or_spec.rb

Comment: @JörgWMittag Unfortunately, the ISO spec and Pickaxe book are woefully out of date so I don't want to point anyone at them without a lot of handwaving and caveats. The spec suite (which [ruby-doc.org](https://ruby-doc.org)) thankfully points to) misses a lot of "obvious" things that Ruby has inherited from other languages (such as `false || 6` being `6` rather than `true`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is kind of weird piece of code, but this is what its doing:

you are defining a method called `method`

the special method `super` means to call the same named method on the parent (super) class.

the you are taking the result of `super`, which must be an "enumerable" object, such as an Array or a hash and calling `select` on that object

`select` goes through the enumerable object (lets assume its an array) and calls the block with each element.   Typically its used to filter (or select) some objects from the array.   Each time the block is called it returns a truthy or falsy value.  If truthy then that element is kept in the resulting array.  If falsy its thrown out.

Okay so every element of this array is going to have this executed on it:

`a.meets_condition? || true`

which is bizarre because what this is going to do is call `meets_condition?` on the element of the array, and if it returns a truthy value then that element (a) is kept in the array.

but what if `a.meets_condition?` is falsy?

Then we go on to the next part of the `or` (the double pipes) and do that.

Which returns true.

So basically this expression is going to return a copy of the array you passed in.

Lets make the example into an actual working example:

```
class RandomDigit
  # gives you a object containing a random digit between 0 and 9
  def initialize
    @n = rand(10)
  end
  def meets_condition?  # returns true if @n is even 
    @n % 2 == 0 
  end
end

class TheParentClass
  def method
    # returns array of 4 random digits (between 0 and 9)
    [RandomDigit.new, RandomDigit.new, RandomDigit.new, RandomDigit.new]
  end
end

class TheChildClass < TheParentClass
  def method
    # super means we are calling TheParentClass.method
    # select will try each element of the the array 
    # and builds a new array, with elements that returned true
    # but the trouble is || true means its always going to return true
    super.select { |a| a.meets_condition? || true }
  end
end

puts TheChildClass.new.method # -> returns 4 random digits
```

You can click on this link to run the code and see it work

http://opalrb.com/try/?code:class%20RandomDigit%0A%20%20def%20initialize%0A%20%20%20%20%40n%20%3D%20rand(10)%0A%20%20end%0A%20%20def%20meets_condition%3F%0A%20%20%20%20%40n%20%25%202%20%3D%3D%200%20%23%20returns%20true%20if%20%40n%20is%20even%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0Aclass%20TheParentClass%0A%20%20def%20method%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20returns%204%20random%20digits%20(between%200%20and%209)%0A%20%20%20%20%5BRandomDigit.new%2C%20RandomDigit.new%2C%20RandomDigit.new%2C%20RandomDigit.new%5D%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0Aclass%20TheChildClass%20%3C%20TheParentClass%0A%20%20def%20method%0A%20%20%20%20super.select%20%7B%20%7Ca%7C%20a.meets_condition%3F%20%7C%7C%20true%20%7D%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0Aputs%20TheChildClass.new.method

Just to be clear the only thing that doesn't really make sense here is the `|| true` part.

Otherwise this would be that you are defining a new class, and you are slightly changing the behavior of `method` so that it works sort of like the original `method` but filters out the elements.

Usually you might see something like `a.question_1? || a.question_2?`

which would be try question_1? and if it returns true then we are done.

if it doesn't return true, then try question_2.

This is because `||` is a flow of control operation... the second part does NOT get executed if the first part is already true.

`&&` is the opposite, in the since that the second part does not get executed unless the first part is true.

Answer (score 0):

This method calls the method with the same name from the parent class and then calls `#select` method for returned value.
Example:

```
class Class1
  def method
    puts 'OK'
    'NOT OK'
  end
end

class Class2 < Class1
  def method
    puts super.downcase
  end
end

Class2.new.method
```

This will print:

> OK
>   not ok

Method `Class2#method` calls method `Class1#method` (`Class1#method` prints 'OK' and returns 'NOT OK') and then downcases returned *String* **'NOT OK'** to **'not ok'** and prints it.

In your example, two vertical lines in block for `#select` mean ***'boolean OR'*** and the whole expression `a.meets_condition? || true` can be used for two reasons:

1. It can be evaluated to result of calling `a.meets_condition?` (if this result is not `true` or `nil`) or to the `true` otherwise.
2. It can throw an exception if `a.meets_condition?` throws an exception. This exception can be caught and handled at the upper level of the call stack.